# A service with multiple instances

Tags: android, service

I am implementing an app which uses an activity and a  service. n my activity there is a listview which consists of a button. y activity passes two params to the service when a button of a listview item is pressed. But what if i choose multiple option  i.e. items. Since the activity uses the same service is it possible to create a new instance of the same service with different params when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a lot of information about how to instantiate and how to pass parameters to a service:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

About your question, a service is unique. If you want that this service do a different work, create a new one. But you can send as many params as you want and manage them in

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
```